# Finding the sum of series with factorials

Tags: sequences-and-series

This is from my math quiz so it must be something not too  long here it goes:
If $1\cdot(0)!+3\cdot(1!)+7\cdot(2!)+13\cdot(3!)+21\cdot(4!)+\cdots$ up to $n$ terms equals $=(4000)4000!$ then the value of $n$ I tried to make it a telescopic series but failed..

Comment: Look at the first several terms and see if you can spot a pattern.  $1*(0)!+3*(1!)=4=2*2!$. Then  $1*(0!)+3*(1!)+7*(2!)=18=3*3!$ etc... What is the next term in the sequence?  Can you make a conjecture about what it equals in general?  Can you prove your conjecture is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. You are summing terms of the form 
$$(1^2-0)\cdot(0)!+(2^2-1)\cdot(1!)+(3^2-2)\cdot(2!)+(4^2-3)\cdot(3!)+(5^2-4)\cdot(4!)+\cdots$$.